# RedisLab with WordPress Integration Error: PHP Warning: Redis::select() expects parameter 1 to be integer

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, redis, phpredis

I am trying to add a Redis object cash server with my WWrdPress site. I am following this [article](https://developer.ibm.com/marketplace/docs/technical-scenarios/using-redis-cloud-servcie-enable-wordpress-caching/)  and I've crated account in redislabs.com

As per the tutorial, my `object-cache.php` file has

```
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_HOST", "HOST_URL");
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_PORT", "12345");
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_DB", "DATABAES_NAME");
 define("WP_REDIS_PASSWORD", "PA$$WORD");
```

and

```
347         $this->redis->auth( $redis['password'] );
348
349         if ( isset( $redis['database'] ) ) {
350           $this->redis->select( $redis['database'] );
351         }
```

But I get this error in line 350

Error

> [Sun Apr 30 19:54:30.579728 2017] [:error] [pid 1750] [client
>   162.158.26.98:21176] PHP Warning:  Redis::select() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in /var/www/public/wordpress/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 350, referer:
>   mysite.com/about-us/

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Redis Cloud, and other responsibly-minded Redis-as-a-Service providers, supports only the default database name (or 0). Just remove lines 349-351 from the file, or `define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_DB", 0);` 
and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a [strongly typed comparison of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), meaning `phpredis` is looking or database name and port to be of type `integer`, but putting them in `""` [makes them `strings`](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/php/). When you compare variables with `===` vs. `==` both type and value match, e.g. `1 !== '1'`.

As Itamar mentioned, Redis database "names" are actually numbers, they don't have string names like other databases.

Try:

```php
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_HOST", "HOST_URL");
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_PORT", 12345); // this is different
 define("WP_REDIS_BACKEND_DB", 0); // this is different
 define("WP_REDIS_PASSWORD", "PA$$WORD");
```